# Killing of so many people in Misfits?

Tags: plot-explanation, misfits

In the television series, Misfits, throughout the various seasons, We see the main characters killing a large number of people - many of the probation workers, cheerleaders etc...

And we just see a casual mention of the cops. No serious enquiry ever is taken and they never find themselves in any serious trouble? Is it a plot hole or am I missing something?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a plot hole. It'd be pretty annoying if each episode consisted of police interrogations concerning the previous episode.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely not a plot hole, but you are definitely not missing anything; it is simply a modified version of the **reset button**.

In the season 2 premiere, Nathan addresses the body count, "Can we please stop killing our probation workers?" as a joke, and then nothing happens.

It's South Park syndrome: while main characters can change (Mr/s Garrison) and people can leave and enter the cast (Tweak, Pip, Chef), there could be a massive body count and police would never notice save for maybe that episode.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of people who died in the Misfits are missing persons cases. No bodies are ever found. The Misfits end up using first probation worker credit cards to make the police think he just took off. The second they bury. Both are shown not to have many friends or connections. The third is a prick and no one really cares about him.

And to top it off, all this happens in relation to the storm, which likely has the cops busy elsewhere. As the series shows, people are cynical about ASBO, juvenile delinquents, drug dealers, etc. Not like they live in the posh part of town.